# HTML-Only Website w/ Theme Options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, themes

I am creating a html-only(no server sided code) website that supposed to have multiple themes,

Wherein user can select/change a theme to view the website.

Can you suggest some concepts on how to do this or at least point me into some helpful articles.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably overkill... but here is a font selector example I came up with using Google Font API and a [Document Fragment Builder](http://rlemon.github.com/FragBuilder.js/) script I wrote a while ago.

```
var FragBuilder = (function() {
    var applyStyles = function(element, style_object) {
        for (var prop in style_object) {
            element.style[prop] = style_object[prop];
        }
    };
    var generateFragmentFromJSON = function(json) {
        var tree = document.createDocumentFragment();
        json.forEach(function(obj) {
            if (!('tagName' in obj) && 'textContent' in obj) {
                tree.appendChild(document.createTextNode(obj['textContent']));
            } else if ('tagName' in obj) {
                var el = document.createElement(obj.tagName);
                delete obj.tagName;
                for (part in obj) {
                    var val = obj[part];
                    switch (part) {
                    case ('textContent'):
                        el.appendChild(document.createTextNode(val));
                        break;
                    case ('style'):
                        applyStyles(el, val);
                        break;
                    case ('childNodes'):
                        el.appendChild(generateFragmentFromJSON(val));
                        break;
                    default:
                        if (part in el) {
                            el[part] = val;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
                tree.appendChild(el);
            } else {
                throw "Error: Malformed JSON Fragment";
            }
        });
        return tree;
    };
    var generateFragmentFromString = function(HTMLstring) {
        var div = document.createElement("div"),
            tree = document.createDocumentFragment();
        div.innerHTML = HTMLstring;
        while (div.hasChildNodes()) {
            tree.appendChild(div.firstChild);
        }
        return tree;
    };
    return function(fragment) {
        if (typeof fragment === 'string') {
            return generateFragmentFromString(fragment);
        } else {
            return generateFragmentFromJSON(fragment);
        }
    };
}());

function jsonp(url) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = url;
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(script);
}

function replacestyle(url) {
    if (!document.getElementById('style_tag')) {
        var style_tag = document.createElement('link');
        style_tag.rel = 'stylesheet';
        style_tag.id = 'style_tag';
        style_tag.type = 'text/css';
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style_tag);
        replacestyle(url);
    }
    document.getElementById('style_tag').href = url;
}

function loadFonts(json) {
    var select_frag = [
        {
        'tagName': 'select',
        'id': 'font-selection',
        'childNodes': [
            {
            'tagName': 'option',
            'value': 'default',
            'textContent': 'Default'}
        ]}
    ];
    json['items'].forEach(function(item) {
        var family_name = item.family,
            value = family_name.replace(/ /g, '+');

        if (item.variants.length > 0) {
            item.variants.forEach(function(variant) {
                value += ':' + variant;
            });
        }

        select_frag[0].childNodes.push({
            'tagName': 'option',
            'value': value,
            'textContent': family_name
        });
    });

    document.getElementById('container').appendChild(FragBuilder(select_frag));
    document.getElementById('font-selection').onchange = function(e) {
        var font = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,
            name = this.options[this.selectedIndex].textContent;
        if (font === 'default') {
            document.getElementById('sink').style.fontFamily = 'inherit';
        } else {
            document.getElementById('sink').style.fontFamily = name;
            replacestyle('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=' + font);
        }
    };
}

jsonp("https://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/v1/webfonts?key=AIzaSyDBzzPRqWl2eU_pBMDr_8mo1TbJgDkgst4&sort=trending&callback=loadFonts");​
```

Here is the [Kitchen Sink](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/ENpWt/) example...

Comment: Now thats vanilla at its best , overkill though but yeah that could be used to do what he wants [ with a bit twist ]

Comment: technically speaking now that I look at it the replacestyle method should accept a callback, when the link is finished loading then replaces the body fontFamily. If loading is an issue you could also show a modal overlay with a 'processing..' message or something ?

Answer (score 3):

The most common approach is to use different external CSS stylesheets, that will get switched based on the selected theme. You also need to structure your DOM wisely, so as to allow different layouts provided by themes.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery style switchers. Check out below link which also have step-by-step tutorials on how to do it:

http://www.net-kit.com/10-practical-jquery-style-switchers/

There is also an article of how to do it here:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/jquery-style-switcher/

Comment: The OP wants to learn how to do this and wants articles on how its implemented , jQuery is an easy solution but will abstract nearly all the learning from the OP

Comment: Actually the page also have tutorials that shows how you do it.

Comment: its actually a good article, the only problem is... i'm not allowed to create server pages for some reasons, the tutorial uses PHP to create cookies and retrieve them as selected style. Do you think there is a way to do this using javascript only? If they allowed me to create aspx or php pages i would not be asking on how to do this. thanks by the way for the nice articles.. i was reading it and trying it also

Comment: Sure, one of the examples in above article is here: http://www.cssnewbie.com/simple-jquery-stylesheet-switcher/ It show step-by-step how to only use jQuery and CSS. Since jQuery is client side you should be okay.

Comment: Why even use jQuery it can be done in a faster and more efficient way with javascript - vanilla

Comment: I'd suggest @rlemon's fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/ENpWt/ . Read the code. Don't care about the `FragmentBuilder` object though, it may not be worth your time, but would certainly gain you some knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Cudos answered already to this question but I'll post this anyway.

You can modify this tutorial (http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/jquery-style-switcher/) posted by Cudos to consist only of client side code with these modifications to `index.php` file.

Remove the PHP block and add this function.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  function readCookie(name) {
  var nameEQ = name + "=";
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';');

  for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
  }
 return null;
}

var js_style = readCookie(style);
</script>
```

And replace the PHP style switcher with this.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  if (typeof js_style == 'undefined') { js_style = 'day'; }
  document.write('<link id="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/' + js_style + '.css" rel="stylesheet" />');
</script>
```

Worked for me...

Answer (score 0):

As Alexander Pavlov writes in his answer, use different external style sheets. To make it possible to users to select a theme persistently (i.e., so that the theme is preserved when moving to another page of the site, or when returning to the site next day), use either HTTP cookies or HTML5-style localStorage. They let you store information locally in the user’s computer, without any server-side code.

There are many tutorials on localStorage (also known as HTML storage or Web storage), and it’s difficult to pick up any particular. They are more flexible than cookies, and they could be used to store large amounts of data, even user-tailored stylesheets. The main problem with localStorage is lack of support on IE 7 and earlier. You might decide that people using them just won’t get the customizability. Alternatively, you can use cookiers, userData (IE), dojox.storage, or other tools to simulate localStorage on antique browsers.